# Access elements inside a nested embedded within a list inside a dictionary individually

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to access the data inside the companies list which is inside a dictionary which indeed is a list.
I'm getting "**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices**" when i run this code. The j loop takes the first list in the item and iterates it with till every element inside the 'companies' is covered, but i'm not getting why is it not working. Any suggestions would be really helpful

```
l= [{ "id":"a","name":"rocky","companies": ["1","2","3"], "data":"", "data2": {"x","y"} },
    {"id":"b","name":"duster","companies": ["4","5","6"], "data":"", "data2": {"h","p"} } ]


for i in l:
    name=i['name']
    id=i['id']
    for j in l[i]['companies']:
        cmp= j

Output:
id name companies
a   rocky 1
a   rocky 2
a   rocky 3
b   rocky 4
b   duster 5
b   duster 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to index your loop using a list entry, rather than an index. Use this, for example:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(l):
    name=i['name']
    id=i['id']
    for j in l[idx]['companies']:
        cmp= j
```

Now, idx is an integer which is needed to index your list "l"

Comment: correct but idx will iterate till till every element of the list. What i meant is.. for j in l[0]['companies].....at this point 'j' will look up for all the values inside the companies and store it.

Comment: If we change - in my answer - "cmp= j" into "print(f'{id} {name} {j}')" you will get the exact output you described in your question. 

If that is not what you want, please clarify the expected output

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are using item in the list like an index `for j in l[i]['companies']`. Here `i` is not the index but the item itself.

You can fix it by using `i` to get the `companies` like `for j in i['companies']`

One other way to get the result is using `list-comprehension` and `itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter

items = [itemgetter('id', 'name', 'companies')(x) for x in l]
result = [tuple(zip([a]*len(c), [b]*len(c), c)) for a, b, c in items]
```

Comment: i is basically an INTEGER, if we translate your logic it will be something like " for j in 0['companies] " . How can there be an element " 0['companies]' , ideally it should be l[i]['companies] right?

Comment: `i` is not the index, in pyhton `for i in list`, `i` is each item in the list. If you want the index then `for id, val in enumerate(list)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code. 1st one with your input `list`. 2nd one, syntactical error in your code.

```
for i in l:
    name=i['name']
    id=i['id']
    for j in l[i]['companies']:
        cmp= j
```

Here, `i` is a dictionary itself, you cant put it to parse list `l` with inner for lop `l[i]['companies']`. This is the reason you are getting the error: `"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices"`

**Corrected input list `l`:**

```
l = [{ "id":"a","name":"rocky","companies": ["1","2","3"], "data":"", "data2": {"x","y"}} ,{"id":"b","name":"duster","companies": ["4","5","6"], "data":"", "data2": {"h","p"} } ]
```

**Modified Code**

```
count = 0
print("id name companies")
for i in l:
    name=i['name']
    id=i['id']
    #print(l[count])
    for j in l[count].get("companies"):
        cmp = j
        print("{}  {}  {}".format(id, name, cmp))
    count += 1
```

**Output**

```
id name companies
a  rocky  1
a  rocky  2
a  rocky  3
b  duster  4
b  duster  5
b  duster  6
```